# Chemistry of a proposed Capsaicin extract

Tags: everyday-chemistry, food-chemistry, extraction

## Background:

I’d like to make an extract of capsaicin using the following ingredients: Capsicum powder, Fractionated coconut MCT oil, apple cider vinegar, and saline. The idea is for the capsaicin to undergo absorption from the capsicum and into the oil to create an extract. The apple cider vinegar will be used as an emulsifier so I can mix the solution with saline. I chose these specific ingredients because they work well with my particular use case, but let me know if I should use a different solvent and or emulsifier (I'd like it to be food safe, and I'd like to avoid alcohol.)

## Proposed process:

1. Combine MCT oil and Capsicum powder and heat to around to around 250° F and let cool
2. Filter out the leftover solids using a coffee filter
3. Combine with apple cider vinegar and saline.

## Questions (in order of importance):

1. Could this combination of ingredients react to create unwanted chemical byproducts?
2. Is capsaicin soluble in Fractionated coconut MCT oil, or will I need to use a different kind of oil?
3. Will this proposed process actually “extract” the capsaicin from the capsicum powder, or is additional processing required?
4. How should I determine the ratio of ingredients?
5. How long should I keep the oil & Capsaicin over heat?
6. I used the term “extract” to describe this, but is it actually a decoction, infusion or something else?
7. Any other tips, suggestions, warnings?

I know just enough about chemistry to know that I should probably ask questions before giving this a go.

Comment: Some of this might be answered at https://cooking.stackexchange.com/ As for your questions, I would answer: (1) depends. Why are you concerned about chemical byproducts? For safety, taste, other? (2,3) probably. Run tests. (4) Run tests (5) As little as possible (6) extraction is the right term; the other are cooking terms (7) test test test; chemistry is largely an empirical science. Also, google works wonders: search for "oil solubility capsaicin"

Comment: See for instance: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/263619725_Effect_of_vegetable_oil_in_the_solubility_of_capsaicinoids_extracted_from_capsicum_Chinense_Bhut_Jolokia